# What's the shortcut to close vscode's message box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a shortcut to close the message box shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>esc</kbd> should dismiss all visible messages.

You can also configure a custom keybinding for the `leaveEditorMessage` command (or `workbench.action.closeMessages` on older VS Code versions). Here's the default keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "escape",
  "command": "leaveEditorMessage",
  "when": "messageVisible"
}
```

Comment: Mine is <kbd>shift+esc</kbd> though.

Comment: The vim plugin captures `esc`.

Comment: Command `"workbench.action.closeMessages"` doesn't seem to be available anymore. Do you happen to know if it's been renamed or removed altogether?

Comment: Try `leaveEditorMessage`

Comment: @MattBierner thanks, but I still didn't quite manage to get a new keybinding working with that. Even though the keybindings editor does recognize the command, using the keybinding I've selected (ctrl+k ctrl+l) doesn't actually close error messages coming from extensions. Esc works (with vim disabled). Are error messages separate from OP's warning messages or am I just unable to get a new keybinding working? Although I _am_ able to set, say, `editor.action.commentLine` to ctrl+k ctrl+l correctly.

Answer (score 14):

Updated, as of Jan 2020:

```
{
    "key": "shift+escape",
    "command": "notifications.clearAll"
}
```